# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aspose/cells/FileFormatUtil Error when running Spring Boot project on Apache tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, aspose

I am getting error while running method, when i run the code as tomcat server.
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aspose/cells/FileFormatUtil"
I have created a spring boot project.
I am able to execute the method:isSafe when I run the project as Spring Boot

[image]
'''

```
public static boolean isSafe(File f) throws Exception {
        boolean safeState = false;
        // try {
        if ((f != null) && f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
            // Perform a first check on Excel document format
            FileFormatInfo formatInfo = FileFormatUtil.detectFileFormat(f.getAbsolutePath());
            String formatExtension = FileFormatUtil.loadFormatToExtension(formatInfo.getLoadFormat());
```

'''

I have got the error,
When the same project run as a server

[image]

I have added the latest dependency for aspose cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idea user. But think that you should include library as maven dependency and library will be packed in archive (jar,war,ear). Now it seems like it provided to classpath separately and standalone tomcat doesn't have that library in his own libs.

Comment: Yes,
I have added the jar to the lib folder manually after creating a war for the time being using 7zip via archive

Comment: You can add that dependency with maven. Why do you use manual steps?